Send Message from Java to MQ results MQ error 2063 randomly for certain users
The following Java Program is an example of the code that is used to send message to IBM MQ. This is used to explain the problem:
import com.ibm.mq.MQC;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked","deprecation" })

public class TestIBMMQ {

    static String theQueueMgr;
    static String theRequestQueue;
    static String respQueue;
    static String mesgId = null;
    static String corrId = null;
    static MQQueue objQueue = null;
    static String replyQueue;
    static String replyQmgr;

    static boolean isSSLActive;


    public TestIBMMQ() {

    }

    public static ResourceBundle getProperties(String file) {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(file);
        return resourceBundle;
    }

    public static String getFileContent(String path) {
        StringBuffer stringbuffer = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(path);

            FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
            stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String s = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String s1;
            while ((s1 = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringbuffer.append(s1);
                stringbuffer.append(s);
            }
            filereader.close();
            bufferedreader.close();
        } catch (IOException ioexception) {
            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringbuffer.toString();
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String msgText, MQQueueManager qMgr, boolean isResponse) {
        try {

            String theQueueMgr = <fetch Queue Manager Name>;
            String theRequestQueue = <fetch Request Queue Name>;

            if (theRequestQueue != null && theRequestQueue.length() > 0) {

                objQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(theRequestQueue, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT, null, null, null);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Request Queue (request_queue) was not configured! Tool now tries to get any response..");
            }

            MQMessage mqmessage = new MQMessage();

            if (resBund.getString("message_expiry") != null && resBund.getString("message_expiry").length() > 0) {
                mqmessage.expiry = Integer.valueOf(resBund.getString("message_expiry"));
            }

            // The default value is MQC.MQEI_UNLIMITED (-1), which means that
            // the message never expires.
            System.out.println("Message expiry set to ... " + mqmessage.expiry);

            if (!mesgId.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                mqmessage.messageId = mesgId.getBytes();
                // mqmessage.correlationId = mesgId.getBytes();
            } else {
                mqmessage.messageId = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
            }

            if (!corrId.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                mqmessage.correlationId = corrId.getBytes();
            } else {
                mqmessage.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
            }

            mqmessage.writeString(msgText);

            if (!isResponse) {
                mqmessage.replyTotheQueueMgrName = resBund.getString("replyToQmgr");
                mqmessage.replyToQueueName = resBund.getString("replyToQueue");
            }

            MQPutMessageOptions mqputmessageoptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            objQueue.put(mqmessage, mqputmessageoptions);

            System.out.println("Message successfully PUT... ");
        } catch (MQException mqexception) {
            System.out.println("An MQSeries error occurred : Completion code " + mqexception.completionCode + " Reason code " + mqexception.reasonCode);
            System.out.println(mqexception.getCause());
        } catch (IOException ioexception1) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred whilst writing to the message buffer: " + ioexception1);
            ioexception1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred : " + exception.getMessage());
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (objQueue != null)
                    objQueue.close();
                // qMgr.disconnect();
            } catch (MQException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ATSException {

        String prop;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            prop = args[0];
        } else {
            prop = "<some properties file...";
        }

        resBund = getProperties(prop);

        // MQ Objects
        theQueueMgr = resBund.getString("queue_manager");
        theRequestQueue = resBund.getString("request_queue");
        respQueue = resBund.getString("response_queue");
        mesgId = resBund.getString("mesg_id");
        corrId = resBund.getString("corrID");

        MQQueueManager qMgr = null;

        Hashtable mqProperties = new Hashtable();
        mqProperties.put(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, resBund.getString("host"));
        mqProperties.put(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, resBund.getString("channel"));
        mqProperties.put(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, Integer.parseInt(resBund.getString("port")));
        mqProperties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
        
        if (resBund.getString("ssl_active") != null && resBund.getString("ssl_active").equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            isSSLActive = true;
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", resBund.getString("sslmq.trust.store"));
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", resBund.getString("sslmq.key.store"));
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", ATSPasswordEncoder.decode(resBund.getString("mqssl.keystore.pwd")));
        }
        

        try {

            File targDir = new File(resBund.getString("msg_file_path"));

            if (!isSSLActive) {
                qMgr = new MQQueueManager(theQueueMgr, mqProperties);
            } else {
                mqProperties.put(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, resBund.getString("sslmq.cipher.suite"));
                qMgr = new MQQueueManager(theQueueMgr, mqProperties);
            }

            if (resBund.getString("send_req") != null && resBund.getString("send_req").equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                if (targDir.isDirectory()) {
                    for (File file : targDir.listFiles()) {
                        if (theRequestQueue != null && theRequestQueue.length() > 0) {
                            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is being sent to Queue ..... " + theRequestQueue);
                            sendMessage(getFileContent(file.getAbsolutePath()), qMgr, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (qMgr != null) {
                qMgr.disconnect();
                qMgr = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (qMgr != null) {
                try {
                    qMgr.disconnect();
                } catch (MQException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                qMgr = null;
            }
        }
    }// main ends

}

The client library used from IBM is the JAR com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client.jar. I unzipped this JAR file and located the MANIFIST.MF file. I think this is the version of MQ from the MANISIFT.MF file:
Specification-Title: Java Message Service
Specification-Version: 3.0
Specification-Vendor: Eclipse Foundation
Implementation-Title: IBM MQ classes for JMS
Implementation-Version: 9.3.0.0 - p930-L220606
Implementation-Vendor: IBM Corporation
Main-Class: com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.tools.JakartaMainController

The MQ Server is installed on Windows server 2019, and MQ server is version 9.3. In general, the above Java program or the overall approach used based on the above Java code is working fine.
The user running the above program exists in two domains DEV and PROD. I don't understand why exactly, but this is how it works.
The user accounts (for DEV and PROD) who is executing the PUT using the above Java program are added to the mqm and admins group of the MQ Server, and also are assigned the permission to log on as a service.
To test sending a message to the MQ server, the user logs on to a DEV machine using his DEV account (domain), and runs the above program and it will execute the PUT to MQ server using SSL successfully. No issues most of the times.
The following is the problem
It was observed that if a user logs in to the MQ Server (using DEV or PROD accounts) to work with MQ Explorer, to browse the MQ Queues for example using MQ Explorer, then at random cases, the same user will no longer be able to send messages to the MQ server but all the other users can run the program above to send messages to MQ. The following are the errors received in this case:
Error from Java Program:
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2063'.

Error from MQ server in C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QueueMangerName\errors\AMQERR01:
----- amqrimna.c : 911 --------------------------------------------------------
11/21/2024 01:37:37 - Process(6976.19) User(MQ_USER) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(HOST_NAME) Installation(Installation2)
                      VRMF(9.3.5.0) QMgr(QueueMgrName)
                      Time(2024-11-21T07:37:37.774Z)
                      CommentInsert1(UNKNOWN (1722) - The RPC server is unavailable.)
                     
AMQ7227W: IBM MQ encountered the following network error: UNKNOWN (1722) - The
RPC server is unavailable.

EXPLANATION:
MQ failed to successfully complete a network operation due to the specified
error. If the error is encountered on systems that are part of a Windows 2000
domain it can indicate incorrect DNS or WINS configuration.
ACTION:
Ensure that your network is functioning correctly. On the Windows platform
check DNS and/or WINS settings to ensure that domain controllers, used for
authentication or authorisation functions, are accessible.
----- amqzfubn.c : 4130 -------------------------------------------------------
11/21/2024 01:37:37 - Process(7556.6) User(MQ_USER) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(HOST_NAME) Installation(Installation2)
                      VRMF(9.3.5.0) QMgr(QueueMgrName)
                      Time(2024-11-21T07:37:37.777Z)
                      ArithInsert1(2) ArithInsert2(2063)
                      CommentInsert1(windows_acc_running_java_program)
                     
AMQ9557E: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize a user ID failed with CompCode 2 and Reason 2063. 

The channel MCA user at the time of the failure is 'windows_acc_running_java_program'. If an MQCSP
structure was sent by a client, the user ID in the MQCSP is ''. The user ID is
displayed as '*TOKEN' if the client supplied an authentication token in the
MQCSP structure. 

The client remote user ID is ''. Any CHLAUTH rules applied prior to user
adoption were evaluated case-sensitively against this value.
ACTION:
Check for previous error messages that indicate the cause of the problem.
Correct the error and try again.

It was then observed that if the user accounts created for the user who logged in to the MQ server are deleted from C:\USERS for DEV and PROD and also the RegEdit entries are deleted from Windows NT\ProfileList for the related user accounts, check the permissions and group members assignment, and after restarting the MQ Server, the PUT will then work successfully using the above Java program.
A new MQ Server 9.3 was installed on Linux and successfully used the above program to send message to the MQ Server on Linux, and so far we didn't face this problem maybe because we don't login to Linux-based MQ Server. The strange thing is we didn't give any permissions to the user accounts of the users who runs the above program, and still it is working without any problem.
Any idea how to resolve this problem?
I am thinking to create a special user account to logon to the MQ Server on Windows to use MQ Explorer. Or, install MQ Explorer on the DEV server (not on the MQ Server).
If you have any recommendations please let me know.

Is the user having issues a local windows user or a domain user or is there both in existence? The error AMQ7227W: IBM MQ encountered the following network error: UNKNOWN (1722) - The RPC server is unavailable. is strange,  do you have WINS configured?


The user accounts (for DEV and PROD) who is executing the PUT using
the above Java program are added to the mqm and admins group of the MQ
Server, and also are assigned the permission to log on as a service.

That is an incredibly bad idea. Instead of doing proper MQ security, you put the user in the mqm group. Nobody except for the 'mqm' UserId should be in the mqm group, period, end of story. The MQAdmin(s) should/will be using sudo to gain the correct privileges.
The MQ error message shows that the server is running MQ v9.3.5.0. What MQ client release are you using with your Java application? Did you have different behaviour with a different release of MQ?
I copied & pasted your code into Eclipse & I gave a ton of errors. If you are going to post code then post working code!!
What is this:
import com.ibm.mq.MQtheQueueMgr;

Why is there a method called getAndPutMessage() in the code but is not invoked by any other method?
The error message gave you the reason for the Reason Code 2063:

The client remote user ID is ''. Any CHLAUTH rules applied prior to
user adoption were evaluated case-sensitively against this value.

Your code did not set a UserId (nor Password), so the MQ client library did not populate the UserId (or Password) fields.
You appear to be using an older release of the MQ client-side JAR files. Is this true?
If your MQ environment and MQ application were to go through a security, it would fail. You should do the following:

Remove the application's UserId from the mqm group
Make sure CHLAUTH and CONNAUTH are configured correctly
Set the correct authorization privileges for the application's UserId
Since the application is connecting to the queue manager in client mode then


mqProperties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);

should be changed to:
mqProperties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);


In the Java application, set the application's UserId and Password:
mqProperties.put(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "app_UID");
mqProperties.put(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "app_pwd");

"MQC" class is depreciated. You should be using the "MQConstants" class or "CMQC" class.



I included a simplified version of the Java program to explain the method used and errors were made while pasting the code. The program works successfully except when the error 2063 occurs. Note that when the error 2063 occurs we can clear it following the recovery steps I mentioned without changing the program. I will reflect the changes you mentioned about TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT and CMQC class and will reflect the changes related to authorization and credentials to see what is the impact. Also, how do you explain it is working with Linux MQ without adding any permissions for any user?

Prior to MQ v6, MQ had a huge security hole in that if you sent a blank UserId which Java applications did by default, the queue manager assigned its own UserId to the connection (i.e. mqm). Hence, you had god authority. So, if I had to guess, you have disabled security features like CONNAUTH & CHLAUTH which means you have exposed the security hole or you removed the CHLAUTH rules which prevented it and/or you put mqm UserId in the MCAUSER field of the channel (again very bad idea). Finally, you didn't answer most of my questions.

For the question Why is there a method called getAndPutMessage()... - It is not needed. I just wanted to showcase the Java program method to send a message to MQ. I fixed the program listing now but I cannot guarantee it will be error free.

I updated the question with all the details your requested. Let me know if I missed any anything.
